# Call non-generic function from a generic class stored in a Type variable at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, reflection

I don't know the best way to phrase this question in the title, so I apologise if it's not the best. 
However I believe the explanation is easy to follow.

I am making a small C# command line shell, and I am implementing each command (e.g. `ls`, `cat`) as a separate class. I am using the [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) library to parse command line options.

Here is my code:

```
//Command.cs
public abstract class Command<T>
{
    public void Run(string[] args)
    {
        Parser.Default.ParseArguments<T>(args)
            .WithParsed(ParseOpts)
            .WithNotParsed(HandleParseError);
    }

    public abstract void ParseOpts(T opts);
    public abstract void HandleParseError(IEnumerable<Error> errs);
}

//Cat.cs
public class Cat : Command<CatOptions>
{
    //...
    public override void ParseOpts(CatOptions opts)
    {
        //...
    }

    public override void HandleParseError(IEnumerable<Error> errs)
    {
        //...
    }
    //other stuff...
}

//CatOptions.cs
class CatOptions
{
    [Option('E', "show-ends", Default = False, 
        HelpText = "display $ at end of each line")]
    public bool ShowEnds { get; set; }

    //other options...
}
```

The way the parser works is that I have to call the boilerplate code that is in `Run` (i.e. `ParseArguments`), which will parse the options in `args` based on the options specified in the options class `T`. If parsing is successful, it will call `ParseOpts`, where the command can access the options and do stuff, or `HandleParseError` if it fails.

I want it so that I don't have to repeat this boilerplate code, but rather just specify the relevant options type `T`, and implement `ParseOpts` and `HandleParseError` as I see fit.

So far, this all makes sense, but I don't know to use it as I want to.

```
public class Shell
{
    //What do I put here?
    private Dictionary<String, ???> Commands = new Dictionary<String, ???>
    {
        {"cat", Cat}, // or new Cat()? typeof(Cat)?
        //other commands...
    };

    //other stuff...

    private void Execute()
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] args = ParseInput(input);

        string cmd = args[0];

        if (Commands.ContainsKey(cmd))
        {
            //What I want to be able to do
            Commands[cmd].Run(args);
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

In my main `Shell` class, I have a Dictionary `Commands` which I use to map command names to their classes. What I want to be able to do is simply get input from the user, parse the command from the input, check if it's in the dictionary, and then `Run` that command, but that's where I am stuck.

I can't declare `Commands` as something like `Dictionary<String, Command<T>>`, because I have to specify what `T` is. I don't know if it's possible to somehow declare `Commands` with a *generic* generic type or something like that.

I also tried storing the `Commands` as `Type`, and then instantiating them at runtime and calling `Run`; like this:

```
private Dictionary<String, Type> Commands = new Dictionary<String, Type>
    {
        {"cat", typeof(Cat)},
        //other commands...
    };
```

But I don't know how to instantiate the class and call `Run` in `Execute` because I need to somehow cast it to a `Command<T>` and specify the appropriate `T` at runtime:

```
if (Commands.ContainsKey(cmd))
{
    //Want to do something like this, but obviously it doesn't work
    //because I have to provide the T type
    var cmdType = Commands[cmd];
    ((Command<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(cmdType)).Run(args);
}
```

At runtime I know that regardless of what class it is they are all of type `Command<T>`, and I can determine the actual class and type `T` based on the command name (e.g. `cat` maps to `CatOptions`).

I know I can do explicit casting like this with if statements:

```
if (cmdType == typeof(Cat))
{
  ((Cat)Activator.CreateInstance(cmdType)).Run(args);
}
else if ...
```

But I don't want to do that because it will repeat code (unless there's a smart way to do it without repeating code?)

What I want is for `Shell` to not have to know about any of the `*Options` classes, and for the `*Options` classes to all be encapsulated within each respective `Command` class.
I know it's possible that my design is just terrible and there's a blatantly simple way of doing this; if so please show me.

I know that there must be some way to do it with reflection, but I have been having difficulty figuring out how to do it.

What can I do in order to get the runtime polymorphism that I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a non generic abstraction

```
public interface ICommandLine {
    void Run(string[] args);
}
```

that the generic abstraction can be derived from

```
public abstract class Command<T>: ICommandLine {

    public void Run(string[] args) {
        Parser.Default.ParseArguments<T>(args)
            .WithParsed(ParseOpts)
            .WithNotParsed(HandleParseError);
    }

    protected abstract void ParseOpts(T opts);
    protected abstract void HandleParseError(IEnumerable<Error> errs);
}
```

Allowing for a simpler implementation

```
//...

private Dictionary<String, ICommandLine> Commands = new Dictionary<String, ICommandLine> {
    {"cat", new Cat()},

    //other commands...
};

//...
```

Comment: It was that simple >_<... Wow. Well, at least it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would add an interface and you can add this instance in dictionary

```cs
public interface ICommand
{
 void Run(string[] args);
}
//Command.cs
public abstract class Command<T> : ICommand
{
    public void Run(string[] args)
    {
        Parser.Default.ParseArguments<T>(args)
            .WithParsed(ParseOpts)
            .WithNotParsed(HandleParseError);
    }

    public abstract void ParseOpts(T opts);
    public abstract void HandleParseError(IEnumerable<Error> errs);
}

//Cat.cs
public class Cat : Command<CatOptions>
{
    //...
    public override void ParseOpts(CatOptions opts)
    {
        //...
    }

    public override void HandleParseError(IEnumerable<Error> errs)
    {
        //...
    }
    //other stuff...
}

//CatOptions.cs
class CatOptions
{
    [Option('E', "show-ends", Default = False, 
        HelpText = "display $ at end of each line")]
    public bool ShowEnds { get; set; }

    //other options...
}
```